# How can a DM nerf the circle of the moon archdruid ability to prevent infinite hit points?

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons

So I know a lot of people argue that infinite wild shape "isn't that overpowered" but I still think gaining upwards of 200 hit points per turn is a bit broken, especially compared to other level 20 abilities like the ranger, who just get to add a wisdom bonus. How would one go about nerfing it so they still are strong, but not un-killable?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange! This is a question we've been asked a few times already. Take a look at this: [Does unlimited Wild Shape make Circle of the Moon archdruids virtually unkillable?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70392/does-unlimited-wild-shape-make-circle-of-the-moon-archdruids-virtually-unkillabl)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.